# Skype ios app sdk - require access to contacts

Tags: ios, skypedeveloper

I have develop and videocall app with Skype for business app sdk - it is working great - but there are an issue - the app does not use the phones contacts - but the SDK requires permissions on the phone to start. Apple have rightfully rejected the app - when we don't have a go answer.

Anyone that has a workaround or knows if Microsoft is coming with a update?

Comment: hi welcome to SO -- I feel the pain. That being said I feel you can only get a good answer from the skype sdk page (e.g. there github page or sdk homepage) dont think there will be anyone being able to help here

Comment: Hi - and thank you for the warm welcome and the advice! - i have already tried Github, so maybe the SDK homepage is the best alternative. It is a bit sad :-(